# Mulitple Ubuntu Subsystems on Windows 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there any way to have multiple Linux Subsystems on Windows 10, each one separate from each other?
Thanks

Comment: This isn't going to be possible.

Comment: As @Ramhound stated, this is not possible.  You should think of a Linux Subsystem in Windows 10 as essentially being the polar opposite of what running Wine on a Linux system does.

Comment: Why is that? Is there a way, then, to backup the current subsystem, uninstall it and install it again using LxRun.exe?

Comment: And then do the same and restore the old one?

Comment: Yes;  There is a even wrote an answer that explains how to uninstall and reinstall it. As to the reason, it is because, **it isn't a feature Microsoft as added**

Comment: I know how to uninstall and reinstall it. What I can't find is how to backup and restore the existing system.

Comment: Actually, with WSL, each user gets their own Linux subsystem.  So if you use different user accounts, your system will have multiple WSLs installed

Comment: Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51584765/how-do-you-install-multiple-separate-instances-of-ubuntu-in-wsl